# Find if there exist homogeneous equation with constant coefficients with the solution $y=x\cos^2(x)-\sin{x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Assuming this is the solution, the complex roots of the polynom of the ODE will look like:

$e^{ax}\cos(bx)$ , $e^{ax}\sin(bx)$  because there are 2 roots at the solution.

We learned that the solution will be a linear combination of these 2 roots.

For $x\cos^2(x)$ I found that $a=\frac{\ln(x\cos^2(x))}{x}$ and $b=1$

Which gives $e^{ax}\cos(bx) = x\cos^2(x)=Z_1$

For $\sin{x}$ (ignoring the minus, as it is one of the constants in the linear combination) we get $a=0$ and $b=1$

Which gives $e^{ax}\sin(bx)=\sin{x}=Z_2$

$a$ is the real part and $b$ is the imaginary part of the complex root.

So if the polynom of the ODE is $r^2+cr+d=0$, by quadratic formula
$Z_{1,2}=\frac{-c\pm \sqrt{c^2-4d}}{x}$

So I can find 2 options for $c$ and $d$. For $Z_2$ with $a=0 ,b=1$ I found that $c=0 , d=1$ for the plus sign, the minus had no solution because $d$ is real.

For $Z_1$ I found that $x\cos(x)$=1 and $\frac{\ln(x\cos(x)}{x}=\pm\sqrt{2}$ which is contradiction. So there is no ODE with the solution mentioned at the top. Is that valid?

Comment: What makes you say there are two roots only? One of the terms in the equation is definitely not of the form $e^{ax}\cos(bx)$. Hint: There's more than two roots (at a minimum, I count that you need at least 8, including multiplicity)

Comment: We learned that the roots are only of the form: $x^{s-1}e^{ax}\cos(bx)$ and $x^{s-1}e^{ax}\sin(bx)$ where $s$ is the "zero of the function" (not sure if thats the name, the number of times the root appears when factoring the polynom)

If there are 2 expressions in the solutions that doesn't mean there are 2 roots?

Comment: That logic is incorrect. If I told you to find me a real valued DE who has one possible homogeneous solution of $\sin x$, how many roots would that equation need minimum? And does the number of roots match the number of expressions I gave you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewriting the given solution, we have that

$$y = \frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2}x\cos 2x - \sin x$$

Complex roots always come in pairs (the root and its conjugate) for real valued ODEs, which means $\pm i$ must be roots from the last term. $x$ is a repeated root for the root $0$, and $x\cos 2x$ accounts for another four roots (one complex conjugate pair, $\pm 2i$, plus their repeats for the correct multiplicity. This means the differential equations is given by

$$D^2(D^2+1)(D^2+4)^2y = 0  $$

an $8$th order linear constant coefficient DE.

Comment: So you found that $b=\pm1$ , $0$ , $\pm2$. What about the values of $a$ in $x^{s-1}e^{ax}\cos(bx)$ , $x^{s-1}e^{ax}\sin(bx)$?

Comment: @amit what is $a$ for a complex number like $2i$?

Comment: I mean you dont see $e$ to the power of something in the solution, how can you know $a=0$ as in $2i$ or $a$ something like I wrote? with $ln$ that canceles the $e$

Comment: @amit what is $e$ to the $0$ power....